# Why is LazyInitializationException happening here?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

So I have this entity with `FetchType.LAZY` collection:

```
@Entity
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OtherEntity> lazyCollection;

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class OtherEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "entity", nullable = false)
private Entity entity;

}
```

And I have the following services:

```
public class ServiceA implements Serializable {
    public Entity loadEntity(Long entityId) {
        return em.find(Entity.class, entityId);
    }
}

public class ServiceB extends ServiceA {
    public Map<? extends X, ? extends Y> load(Long entityId) {
        Entity entity = loadEntity(entityId);
        //play with entity and fill the map with required data
        return prepareMap(entity, map);
    }

    //meant to be overriden in inheriting services
    protected Map<? extends X, ? extends Y> prepareMap(Entity entity,
            Map<? extends X, ? extends Y> map) { return map; }
}

@Stateless
public class ServiceC extends ServiceB {

    @Override
    protected Map<? extends X, ? extends Y> prepareMap(Entity entity,
            Map<? extends X, ? extends Y> map) {
        if (entity.getLazyCollection() != null
                && !entity.getLazyCollection.isEmpty()) {
            // play with entity and put some other data to map
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

Now, I'm trying to call `ServiceB#load` from CDI bean like this:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class void WebController implements Serializable {

    @EJB        
    private ServiceC service;

    public void loadEntity(Long entityId) {
        service.load(entityId);
    }
}
```

But when I get to *`ServiceC`* `entity.getLazyCollection.isEmpty()` call, I get `LazyInitializationException: illegal access to loading collection`. I don't get it why.

Does it mean that after loading, entity somehow became detached?

I even tried to override `ServiceA#loadEntity` method in `ServiceC` to call `entity.getLazyCollection()` to trigger actual loading from database, but I still get this `LazyInitializationException`.

Comment: Are you using JTA EntityManager?

Comment: Not sure, I think it's implemented by Hibernate, since the persistence provider is `Hibernate`.

Comment: How are you obtaining the `EntityManager`?

Comment: Via @PersistenceContext annotation (and persistence.xml configured to use `Hibernate` as persistence provider).

Comment: Well, it seems strange, as you're using JTA container-managed EntityManager. You should be in an active transaction started by ServiceC#load(-) method invocation and have access to the collection.

Comment: Agreed. Usually I get this exception when trying to access lazily-loaded field from CDI bean, which has no access to Hibernate session and operates on detached entity. But this case drives me nuts, because I see no obvious reason for such an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying exception was `EntityNotFoundException`.

`OtherEntity` has a mandatory one-to-one association with `SomeOtherEntity`, which wasn't found in the database. I didn't see it in logs, because logging in our project wasn't set up properly. Other than that, `LazyInitializationException` seems to be weird in this case. Looks like Hibernate wraps `EntityNotFoundException` into `LazyInitializationException`. The reason for doing this isn't clear for me.

Comment: One of Hibernate mysterious deviations ;-)